# Iterate through list with numbers (as text)

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, numbers

I want to iterate through a list of coordinates and see it the last coordinate matches the first coordinate (to make sure polygon is closed). So I want to first select the first and last coordinate in the string, see if they match, and -if not-, add the first coordinate to the string. The coordinates are stored in have a geojson string:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     76.863853437826,
                     2.49314161017537,
                     40.0
                  ],
                  [
                     -76.863723769784,
                     2.4932265188545,
                     0.3
                  ],
                  [
                     -76.8627395667136,
                     2.49319550581276,
                     0.0
                  ],
                  [
                     -76.863853431111,
                     2.4931416101711111,
                     0.0
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "pointCount":"3",
            "length":"0.0",
            "area":"0.00001"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I first use findall method with regex to filter the coordinates from this string. This results in a list with this structure:

```
listx = [
  "76.863853437826,2.49314161017537",
  "-76.863723769784,2.4932265188545",
  "-76.8627395667136,2.49319550581276",
  "-76.863853431111,2.4931416101711111"
]
```

Now, the 'strange' behaviour is that when I use this list in a for loop (for x in list) with an index, it only gives me the first number... Example:

```
for i in listx:
    first_coord = i[0]
    last_coord = i[-1]
    print(first_coord)
```

This results in '7' for the first coordinate. I would expect that it should plot the entire coordinate on index 0 (so: `'76.863853437826,2.49314161017537'`).

I am a Phy-beginner, so probably I don't see something important here. Any solution how I can make sure that the entire coordinate string is being selected (first and last coordinate)? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you parse it yourself instead of using the builtin json library which would do it in just one line?

Answer (score 0):

`'76.863853437826,2.49314161017537'` is still a string, so you are just extracting the first and second character of said string. You can `.split` it at the comma to get the two coordinates:

```
for i in listx:
    coord = i.split(",")
    first_coord = float(coord[0])
    last_coord = float(coord[1])
```

However, as I said in my comment, I'd just use the builtin `json` module to get the data parsed, it's really much more robust.